# changing namespace of express in typescript

Tags: typescript, namespaces, nestjs

I wanna change the express namespace in my typescript file and add another option to it, but eslint get some errors,

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      currentUser?: User;
    }
  }
}
```

Error is:
ES2015 module syntax is preferred over namespaces.

how can i fix this error except change ts rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
declare module 'express' {
  export interface Request {
    currentUser?: User;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but after add this eslint said Property 'session' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>

Comment: Try extending from ```express```'s native ```Request``` interface

Comment: can u write it, sry, I can't understand

Comment: ``import { Request } from 'express'``

declare module 'express' {
  export interface RequestExtended extends Request {
    currentUser?: User;
  }
}

Comment: no, it's not working. 'extends' clause of exported interface 'RequestExtended' has or is using private name 'Request'.